# How to pass variable in django but not as url parameter

Tags: django

I have this in urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^add_to_cart/(?P<app_label>\w+)/(?P<model_name>\w+)/(?P<obj_id>\d+)/$', AddToCart.as_view(), name='add-to-cart'),
    )
```

and i am using this to call AddToCart view in template:

```
{% for eg in eyeglasses %}
<p>{{eg}} <a href="{% url 'add-to-cart' eg|app_label eg|class_name  eg.pk %}" >Buy</a> </p>  
{% endfor %}
```

This ends up in having a url like this

"127.0.0.1/cart/add_to_cart/product/Sunglass/2/"

which i want to avoid. Is there any different way to pass these variables but without passing them as url parameters?

Comment: Well, you'd have to remove them from `urls.py`, and take them as POST parameters in your view (request.POST). This would also mean you couldn't use the `url` template function. But why don't you want them in your URL?

Comment: because this view is showing all cart items in a cart but the urls kinda tell a different story .. its a bit confusing for users.

Comment: You could have the view return an HttpResponseRedirect to your main shopping cart page after it's added the item. This also has the benefit that if your user refreshes the page, he won't add the item again (which would be equally true of a GET parameter, and true with an annoying browser warning if you used a POST parameter.

Answer (score 4):

You can try passing them as querystring parameters instead of in url, so you can build url as

```
http://127.0.0.1/cart/add_to_cart?app_label=product&product=Sunglass&id=2
```

Build this in template as

```
{% for eg in eyeglasses %}
<p>{{eg}} <a href="{% url 'add-to-cart' %}?app_label={{eg.app_label}}&product={{eg.class_name}}&id={{eg.pk}} %}" >Buy</a> </p>  
{% endfor %}
```

In view you can get it as

```
def add_cart_view(request):
    ....
    product_name = request.GET.get('product')
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than having a list of links, create a form where you use buttons of type `submit`. For each button give it a value that you can retrieve from the request. When you submit the form set the method to `post` rather than `get`.

You may want to take a look [part 4](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/intro/tutorial04/) of the [Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/).